# Align Equations in Subequations

Tags: equations, align, subequations

I would like to align these equations as shown in the picture by eq. 3.1.
[image: Optimal control problem]

I tried to use the command \begin{align*} unsuccessfully. My equations are automatically set to the centre, I've also tried to itemise the equations but I do get an error.

```
% --------------
%\begin{align*}
\begin{subequations} \label{eq:optimalsteuerungsprob_zeitkont}
    \begin{equation} \label{eq:optProb_J_Phi_l}
        \min_{\textbf{u} \in \mathcal{A}} \quad J[\textbf{u}(\cdot)] = \varphi\big(t_f, \textbf{x}(t_f)\big) + \int_{t_s}^{t_f} l\big(t,\textbf{x}(t),\textbf{u}(t)\big)\,\mathrm{d}t
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}
        \text{u.B.v.} \quad \dot{\textbf{x}}(t) = \textbf{f}(t,\textbf{x}(t), \textbf{u}(t)) \qquad , \qquad \textbf{x}(0)=\textbf{x}_{0}
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation} \label{eq:optProb_endbedin_PSI}
        \psi\big(\,t_f,\textbf{x}(t_f)\big) = \textbf{0}
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}
        \textbf{h}\big(t,\textbf{x}(t),\textbf{u}()t\big) \le \textbf{0} \quad , \quad \forall t \in [t_{s},t_{f}]
    \end{equation}
\end{subequations}
%\end{align*}
%-----------------
```

Could You please help me in this task for my final thesis?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how  to do that with `alignat`. I systematically replaced `\textbf` with `\mathbf`. Note there also exists a package for optimisation problems formatting, `optidef`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations} \label{eq:optimalsteuerungsprob_zeitkont}
    \begin{alignat}{3} \label{eq:optProb_J_Phi_l}
         & \min_{\mathbf{u} \in \mathcal{A}} & & J[\mathbf{u}(\cdot)] = \varphi\big(t_f, \mathbf{x}(t_f)\big)+ {}& & \int_{t_s}^{t_f} l\big(t,\mathbf{x}(t),\mathbf{u}(t)\big)\,\mathrm{d}t \\[2ex]
         & \text{u.B.v.} & \quad & \dot{\mathbf{x}}(t) = \mathbf{f}(t,\mathbf{x}(t), \mathbf{u}(t)),%
         & & \mathbf{x}(0)=\mathbf{x}_{0} \\ \label{eq:optProb_endbedin_PSI}
         & & & \psi\big(\,t_f,\mathbf{x}(t_f)\big) = \mathbf{0} \\
         & & & \mathbf{h}\big(t,\mathbf{x}(t),\mathbf{u}()t\big) \le \mathbf{0}, %
         & & \forall t \in [t_{s},t_{f}]
    \end{alignat}
\end{subequations}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would use `alignat` inside `subequations` without any additional space between columns. The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{subequations} \label{eq:optimalsteuerungsprob_zeitkont}
\begin{alignat}{2}
  \min_{\textbf{u} \in \mathcal{A}} \quad &J[\textbf{u}(\cdot)] = \varphi\big(t_f, \textbf{x}(t_f)\big)+{}&&\int_{t_s}^{t_f}
        l\big(t,\textbf{x}(t),\textbf{u}(t)\big)\,\mathrm{d}t\label{eq:optProb_J_Phi_l}\\
        \text{u.B.v.} \quad &\dot{\textbf{x}}(t) = \textbf{f}(t,\textbf{x}(t), \textbf{u}(t)),
  &&\textbf{x}(0)=\textbf{x}_{0}\\
  &\psi\big(\,t_f,\textbf{x}(t_f)\big) = \textbf{0}\label{eq:optProb_endbedin_PSI}\\
  &\textbf{h}\big(t,\textbf{x}(t),\textbf{u}()t\big) \le \textbf{0}, &&\forall t \in [t_{s},t_{f}]
\end{alignat}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

The result (see that the second columns in rows 2 and 4 are aligned to the integral sign):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The layout and numbering seems a little unusual, I ended up having to have `align` immediately following another display, then correcting for the bad space that causes.

[image]

Because you are numbering each line of the conditions in the same sequence as the equation you can't use `aligned` as a sub-term, which is what I'd normally use here.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

% --------------

\begin{subequations} \label{eq:optimalsteuerungsprob_zeitkont}
\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:optProb_J_Phi_l}
        \min_{\textbf{u} \in \mathcal{A}} \quad J[\textbf{u}(\cdot)] = \varphi\bigl(t_f, \textbf{x}(t_f)\bigr) + \int_{t_s}^{t_f} l\bigl(t,\textbf{x}(t),\textbf{u}(t)\bigr)\,\mathrm{d}t
\end{equation}
\vspace{-\baselineskip}% sigh
\begin{align}
        \text{u.B.v.} \quad&\dot{\textbf{x}}(t) = \textbf{f}(t,\textbf{x}(t), \textbf{u}(t)), && \textbf{x}(0)=\textbf{x}_{0}
\\ & \label{eq:optProb_endbedin_PSI}
        \psi\bigl(\,t_f,\textbf{x}(t_f)\bigr) = \textbf{0}
\\&
        \textbf{h}\bigl(t,\textbf{x}(t),\textbf{u}()t\bigr) \le \textbf{0},&& \forall t \in [t_{s},t_{f}]
    \end{align}
\end{subequations}
%\end{align*}
%-----------------
\end{document}
```